# How to get purchase_url from API

Tags: soundcloud

I added a buy link to one of my tracks and then tried to access it via API (Ruby wrapper). It displays always empty field.

Updating purchase_url is also not working, while other fields get updated.

Is this a bug or something wrong done on my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your URL?  I'm able to retrieve this info fine from a REST console with a standard GET request.

Using this URL as an example:
https://soundcloud.com/maddecent/grandtheft-mobbin-feat

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/maddecent/grandtheft-mobbin-feat&client_id=[client_id]
```

Returns:

```
{
    "status": "302 - Found",
    "location": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/107686148.json?client_id=[client_id]"
}
```

Hitting the track endpoint:

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/107686148.json?client_id=[client_id]
```

Returns:

```
{
    "kind": "track",
    "id": 107686148,
    "created_at": "2013/08/28 17:24:39 +0000",
    "user_id": 14730,
    "duration": 186766,
    "commentable": true,
    "state": "finished",
    "original_content_size": 9678964,
    "last_modified": "2014/12/30 20:37:07 +0000",
    "sharing": "public",
    "tag_list": "Hedspin \"Mad Decent\" Jeffree's Dance Electronic Club Mobbin",
    "permalink": "grandtheft-mobbin-feat",
    "streamable": true,
    "embeddable_by": "all",
    "downloadable": false,
    "purchase_url": "http://smarturl.it/GrandtheftMOB",
    "label_id": null,
    "purchase_title": "Buy on iTunes",
    "genre": "",
    "title": "Grandtheft - Mobbin feat. Hedspin",
    "description": "Buy on iTunes: http://smarturl.it/GrandtheftMOB\r\nBuy on Beatport: http://bit.ly/GrandtheftBP\r\nBuy on Amazon: http://amzn.com/B00F4IFFQM\r\n\r\nRespected as one of the best live Canadian DJs in the game, Grandtheft has taken a break from globetrotting to pack in a HUGE release for Jeffree’s. Along with World Red Bull Thre3style champ and close pal Hedspin, they have made something minimal but fierce with their track “Mobbin.” The build channels the darkness of No Limit Records at its prime while the drop carries the bounce of a screwed and chopped new jack swing track. That, combined with the most menacing synth stab we’ve heard in a while, makes this tune unstoppable.\r\n\r\nWith “Give Me More,” Grandtheft lends us a soulful track that marries a delicious combination trap and dub in the same vein as his popular remix of Keys N Krates’ song “Treat Me Right” released off of Dim Mak. The juxtaposition of the drop is a total WTF moment for any club-goer and we mean that in the best way possible. Grandtheft’s momentum continues to pick up incredible speed with each release, and we don’t see his rise mellowing out anytime soon.\r\n\r\nGrandtheft\r\nSoundcloud: http://www.soundcloud.com/grandtheft\r\nFacebook: http://facebook.com/grandtheftmusic\r\nTwitter: https://twitter.com/grandtheft\r\nInstagram: http://instagram.com/itsgrandtheft\r\nYoutube: http://youtube.com/grandtheftofficial\r\n\r\nHedspin\r\nSoundcloud: https://soundcloud.com/hedspin\r\nFacebook: https://www.facebook.com/djhedspin\r\nTwitter: https://twitter.com/HEDSPIN\r\nInstagram: http://instagram.com/djhedspin",
    "label_name": "Jeffree's",
    "release": "JEFF060",
    "track_type": "",
    "key_signature": "",
    "isrc": "US-Z4V-13-00221",
    "video_url": null,
    "bpm": null,
    "release_year": 2013,
    "release_month": 9,
    "release_day": 17,
    "original_format": "mp3",
    "license": "all-rights-reserved",
    "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/107686148",
    "user": {
        "id": 14730,
        "kind": "user",
        "permalink": "maddecent",
        "username": "Mad Decent",
        "last_modified": "2014/12/18 18:12:40 +0000",
        "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/14730",
        "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/maddecent",
        "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000112599114-5etg3g-large.jpg"
    },
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/maddecent/grandtheft-mobbin-feat",
    "artwork_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000056426845-b40tmr-large.jpg",
    "waveform_url": "https://w1.sndcdn.com/JL8flUq6Vn0x_m.png",
    "stream_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/107686148/stream",
    "playback_count": 770622,
    "download_count": 16462,
    "favoritings_count": 16626,
    "comment_count": 489,
    "attachments_uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/107686148/attachments",
    "policy": "MONETIZE"
}
```

Purchase info is in the JSON response:

```
"purchase_url": "http://smarturl.it/GrandtheftMOB",
"purchase_title": "Buy on iTunes",
```